# "Persönlichkeit: sein oder haben", what is right?

Tags: usage, vocabulary

I am trying to understand how the word *Persönlichkeit* is used in German, ARE people one, or do they have one?

I was surprised I found on Duden an example with *to be*:
*-er ist eine starke Persönlichkeit;*

I was expecting somehow to see *to have* instead of *to be* there, probably because I am used to say :*"she has a strong personality"* in **English** and *"lei ha una forte personalità"* in **Italian.**

I also found this expression with "to be" in a picture with a quote (see below) that I randomly found on the internet. 
Do you always say *"eine Persönlichkeit sein"* or is it also ok to say *"eine Persönlichkeit haben"*?
[image]

Comment: Look up _Persönlichkeit_ on [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pers%C3%B6nlichkeit) or [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Persoenlichkeit), find three different definitions – mostly the same, actually. 2 and 3 refer to people, 1 refers to a person’s traits, so someone _is_ a 2 or 3 and _has_ a 1. Seems rather obvious to me.

Comment: Persönlichkeit haben, because you have it:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two meanings of the word *Persönlichkeit* — and as logic would have it, one can be *had* while the other only can be *been*.

If you are talking about the personality of somebody, whether they are open-minded, shy, talkative or quick to jump to conclusions, those are traits that require *haben*.

> Du hast eine Persönlichkeit, ich hab eine Persönlichkeit, jeder Mensch hat eine Persönlichkeit.

However, the word *Persönlichkeit* can also be translated as *character* — you can talk about somebody *being* a shy *character* and in this case, it requires *sein*.

> Er ist eine schüchterne Persönlichkeit.

Finally, *Persönlichkeit* can also mean *personage* — and it should be entirely clear that that is something that you *are*, that you cannot *have*.

> Franz Beckenbauer ist eine Persönlichkeit (des öffentlichen Lebens).

So you realise that you can’t automatically choose, you need to think about what you’re saying.

Answer (score 4):

(I am not a linguist, so this might be wrong or inaccurate)

As far as I know, both "eine Persönlichkeit haben" and "eine Persönlichkeit sein" are correct, but have slightly different meanings. "eine ... Persönlichkeit sein" can be loosely translated to "being a ... person", whilst "eine ... Persönlichkeit haben" means "to have a ... personality". I hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with Thomas’ translation for *eine Persönlichkeit haben* …

*Persönlichkeit sein* could mean *to be a celebrity* or *to have some special individual characteristics*.